# Bounds for ${\bf x}' {\bf A} {\bf 1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality

Let $\lambda_{\min}$ and $\lambda_{\max}$ denote the smallest and largest eigenvalues of a symmetric positive definite matrix ${\bf A} \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$. I already know that

$$\lambda_{\min }\| {\bf x} \|^2 \leq {\bf x}' {\bf A} {\bf x} \leq \lambda_{\max }\| {\bf x} \|^2$$

for any real vector $\bf x$, where $\| {\bf x} \|$ denotes the $2$-norm of $\bf x$. I wonder if we can find any bounds for ${\bf x}' {\bf A} {\bf 1}$ (where $\bf 1$ is a vector of ones) based on the minimum or maximum eigenvalues of $\bf A$ and the norm of $\bf x$.

Comment: By Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, we have $-\|x\|_2\|A\mathbf1\|_2\le x^TA\mathbf1\le\|x\|_2\|A\mathbf1\|_2$.

Comment: The proof for $\lambda_{\min }\|x\|^2 \leq  x'Ax  \leq \lambda_{\max }\|x\|^2$ follows from the fact that we can write $x = \sum_{i}^n \xi_i v_i$ where $v_i$ is the $i$-th eigenvector of $A$. Then $x'Ax= \sum \lambda_i \xi_i^2 \leq \sum \lambda_{max}x_i^2 =  \lambda_{max} ||x||^2$.

Comment: You could also apply Cauchy-Schwarz to the inner product induced by $A$: $(x,y)\mapsto x^TAy$. Then $x^TA1 \le \sqrt{ 1^TA1} \sqrt{x^TAx}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Cauchy-Schwarz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality),

$$ \left| {\bf x}^\top {\bf A} \,{\bf 1}_n \right| = \left| {\bf 1}_n^\top {\bf A} \, {\bf x} \right| \leq \underbrace{\| {\bf 1}_n \|_2}_{= \sqrt{n}}  \| {\bf A} \, {\bf x} \|_2 \leq \sqrt{n} \underbrace{\| {\bf A} \|_2}_{= \lambda_{\max} ({\bf A})} \| {\bf x} \|_2 = \color{blue}{\sqrt{n} \,\lambda_{\max} ({\bf A}) \| {\bf x} \|_2} $$

where $\| {\bf A} \|_2 = \lambda_{\max} ({\bf A})$ because $\bf A$ is symmetric positive definite (SPD).

---

**Related**

- [The norm of a positive definite matrix is its largest eigenvalue](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2193891/339790)

Comment: Thank you, can we also derive a lower bound similarly? perhaps like $\sqrt(n)\lambda_{min}(A)||x||_2$? (assuming $x\geq0$)

Comment: @SinaSeyfi The lower bound is the same as the upper bound but with a negative sign. Note that finding the minimum / maximum of a linear function over the unit Euclidean sphere is not the same as finding the minimum / maximum of a quadratic form over the unit Euclidean sphere